# How to cast a Postgres `float8`/`double precision` column to `float4`/`float`?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in a table full of rows called `score`. I'm trying to change the type of this column from `double precision` to `float`. However, my `ALTER TABLE` command isn't working:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "links" 
ALTER COLUMN "score" SET DATA TYPE REAL
```

This gives a `value out of range: underflow` error. Indeed, I can't even `SELECT` with a cast like this:

```sql
postgres=# select "score"::float4 from "links";
ERROR:  value out of range: underflow
```

I also tried casting to `numeric` and to `text` first, but that didn't work either.

```sql
postgres=# select "score"::numeric::float4 from "links";
ERROR:  "0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000230997774471056" is out of range for type real
postgres=# select "score"::text::float4 from "links";
ERROR:  "2.309977744710562e-85" is out of range for type real
```

**What can I do? Also, is there a solution that would work for converting a `double precision[]` column to `float[]`?**

**Info:**

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10. 2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit`

```
postgres=# show extra_float_digits ;
 extra_float_digits 
--------------------
 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: What Postgres version? What does does `show extra_float_digits ;` return? **Add information as update to question.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following hack to resolve my issue:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "links" 
ALTER COLUMN "score" SET DATA TYPE float4 USING round("score"::numeric, 8)::float4,
```

Rounds very small floating point values to zero, which gets rid of the underflow error. It's slow on my large tables, but it seems to work. I don't have a solution for the arrays yet, but I didn't run into that problem :)